# LINQ: Values from one list equal values from another

Tags: c#, linq

I have two lists of objects and I want to compare specific properties.  I want the query to return true if a record from each list has the same values for the properties specified.

I'm currently doing this with nested foreach loops, though I'd like to do this with a single LINQ.

```
bool doesEachListContainSameFullName = false;

foreach (FullName name in NameList)
{
    foreach (FullName anotherName in AnotherNameList)
    {
        if (name.First == anotherName.First && name.Last == anotherName.Last)
        {
            doesEachListContainSameFullName = true;
            break;
        };
    }

    if (doesEachListContainSameFullName)
            break;
}
```

I should add that there are fields in each list that will not equal each other, so comparing the two directly is not an option.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do the same thing using `Any` method

```
return NameList.Any(x => otherList.Any(y => x.First == y.First && 
                                            x.Last == y.Last));
```

Answer (score 2):

[Edited my answer after I understood the requirement]

```
bool doesEachListContainSameFullName = 
    NameList.Intersect(AnotherNameList, new FullNameEqualityComparer()).Any();
```

The `FullNameEqualityComparer` is a simple class that looks like this:

```
class FullNameEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<FullName>
{
    public bool Equals(FullName x, FullName y)
    {
        return (x.First == y.First && x.Last == y.Last);
    }
    public int GetHashCode(FullName obj)
    {
        return obj.First.GetHashCode() ^ obj.Last.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm looking for a record in each list to have values of all properties that I specify to be equal.  I'm not looking for completely equal lists, or completely equal records for that matter.

I'm sorry if that wasn't clear or if I misunderstood your question.

Comment: I'm sorry too I didn't get your intention right. So you only need to know if the two lists contain at least one matching record (compared by properties you specify)?

Comment: Correct.  In this case if there is a record from list A and a record from list B that have the same FirstName and LastName, I want to return true regardless if any other properties match or not.

Comment: OK, then I edit my answer. It is close to @Asad's answer, but with better handling of comparison.